# Is this good way how to resize image before upload?

Tags: php, file-upload

I cannot find some good solution fitted for me for resizing images before upload via PHP so I tried to make own one. But I do not know if there are some problems connected with my solution. I use imagexxx function instead of move_uploaded_file.

Can you please advice me if it is good way and also help to check if security of my code is enough for real use?

UPLOAD PHP code:

```
<?php

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bazar/_inc/DBController.php');
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bazar/_inc/functions.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/_inc/vendor/autoload.php');

// inicialize object
$db_handler = new DBController();

// get total number of files in file list
$total_files = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
// array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(23) "IMG_20190916_105311.jpg" [1]=> string(19) "20180525_115635.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(28) "/home/gm016900/tmp/phpdU58AU" [1]=> string(28) "/home/gm016900/tmp/phpIqWoaQ" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(306091) [1]=> int(2315700) } }

// Create array for jQuery information
$return_arr = array();

$images_names = array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']); // filter just values for $key = name
// -> array(2) { [0]=> string(23) "IMG_20190916_105311.jpg" [1]=> string(19) "20180525_115635.jpg" }
//var_dump($images_names);

// set width and height for thumbnail
$thumb_width = 300;
$uploaded_img_width = 1024;
//$thumb_height = 270;

/* BATCH FILE UPLOAD */

// if $_FILES contains image then do foreach
if ( !empty($images_names) ) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total_files; $i++) {

        // Get reference to uploaded image
        $image_file = $_FILES["files"];

        // Get image name
        $image_name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i];

        // Get file size
        $image_size = $_FILES["files"]["size"][$i];


        /* BASIC CONTROL */

        // Exit if no file uploaded or image name contains unvalid characters /, \\
        if ( ( !strpos($image_name, '/') || !strpos($image_name, '\\') ) && isset($image_file) ) {
            // define variables if image in correct format is uploaded
            $errors = array();
            $maxsize = 10485760;
            $acceptable = array(
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/jpg',
                'image/gif',
                'image/png'
            );
        } else {
            $errors = 'No image uploaded.';
        }

        // Exit if image file is zero bytes or if image size is more then 10 MB
        if (getimagesize($image_file["tmp_name"][$i]) <= 0) {
            $errors = 'Uploaded file has no contents.';
        } elseif ($image_size >= $maxsize) {
            $errors = 'Image is too large. Image must be less than 10 megabytes.';
        }

        if($_FILES['userfile']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $errors = $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
        }

        // Determine the type of an image int|false
        $image_type = exif_imagetype($image_file["tmp_name"][$i]);

        // Exit if is not a valid image file or image has not supported type
        if (!$image_type) {
            $errors = 'Uploaded file is not an image.';
        } elseif ( !in_array($image_file["type"][$i], $acceptable) ) {
            $errors = 'Image has not supported type JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF.';
        } else {
            $src = "default.png";
        }

        if ($errors) { flash()->warning( 'Something went wrong' ); }

        /* CREATE RANDOM IMAGE NAME INSTEDAOF $_FILES['files']['name'] */

        // Get file extension based on file type, to prepend a dot we pass true as the second parameter
        $image_extension = image_type_to_extension($image_type, true);

        // Create a unique image name
        $random_image_name = bin2hex(random_bytes(16)) . $image_extension;


        /* DEFINE LOCATION */

        // Create adress with new img random name
        $relative_location = "/bazar/assets/img/photos/".$random_image_name;

        $absolute_location = dirname(__DIR__, 2).$relative_location;

        $thumb_relative_location = "/bazar/assets/img/photos/thumbs/".$random_image_name;

        $thumb_absolute_location = dirname(__DIR__, 2).$thumb_relative_location;


        //var_dump($image_file["tmp_name"][$i]);
        var_dump($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"]);


        /* MOVE TEMP IMG TO PHOTOS FOLDER */

        // Move img with tmp_name to new location under new random name added from define location section
        //if (move_uploaded_file($image_file["tmp_name"][$i], $absolute_location)) { // move tmp_file to relative_location

        resizeandUpload($random_image_name, $uploaded_img_width, $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $absolute_location);

        /* INSERT IMG_PATH AND THUMB_PATH TO DB */

            $item_id = 1; // get from previous query

            $src = $relative_location;

            //$thumb_src = $thumb_relative_location;

            $query = "INSERT INTO photos (item_id, img_path, thumb_path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

            $inserted = $db_handler->runQuery( $query, 'iss', array($item_id, $src, $thumb_src) );

            //$return_arr .= array("name" => $random_image_name,"size" => $image_size, "src"=> $src);

        /* CREATE THUMBNAIL */
            createThumbnail($random_image_name, $thumb_width, $absolute_location, $thumb_absolute_location);
        //}
    }
}

//echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

FUNCTIONS PHP code:

```
<?php

    /**
    * Secure Output from DB
    *
    * Secure output from db against XSS attacks
    *
    * @param string $str
    * @return string
    */

    function plain ($str) {
        // protection against unauthorized access to code
        return htmlspecialchars( $str, ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    /**
    * Long Text to Short Text
    *
    * Short Long Text to Setted up Lenght
    *
    * @param string $text, int $lenght
    * @return string
    */

    function shortText ($text, $lenght = 180) {
        if ( strlen($text) > $lenght ) {
            $result = substr($text, 0, $lenght) . 'Viac...';
            return $result;
        } else {
            return $text;
        }
    }

    function createThumbnail($filename, $thumb_width, $upload_image_path, $upload_thumbs_path) {

        $upload_image = $upload_image_path;
        $thumbnail_image = $upload_thumbs_path;
        list($width,$height) = getimagesize($upload_image);
        $thumb_height = floor($height * ($thumb_width / $width)); // decrease height same percentage as width
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height); // imagecreatetruecolor() returns an image object representing a black image of the specified size.

        // imagecreatefromjpeg function, which creates the image resource in memory out of the source image path which was initialized in the constructor
        if(preg_match('/[.](jpg|jpeg)$/i', $filename)) {
            $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/i', $filename)) {
            $image_source = imagecreatefromgif($upload_image);
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/i', $filename)) {
            $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($upload_image);
        } else {
            $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
        }

        // Copy and resize part of the image with resampling based on the provided parameters and generates the thumbnail image in memory.
        imagecopyresampled($thumb,$image_source,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);

        // imagejpeg function which saves the in-memory thumbnail image to the desired path on the disk
        if(preg_match('/[.](jpg|jpeg)$/i', $filename)) {
            imagejpeg($thumb,$thumbnail_image,100);
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/i', $filename)) {
            imagegif($thumb,$thumbnail_image,100);
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/i', $filename)) {
            imagepng($thumb,$thumbnail_image,100);
        } else {
            imagejpeg($thumb,$thumbnail_image,100);
        }

    }

    function resizeAndUpload($filename, $thumb_width, $upload_temp_image_path, $upload_image_path) {

        $upload_image = $upload_temp_image_path;
        $thumbnail_image = $upload_image_path;
        list($width,$height) = getimagesize($upload_image);
        $thumb_height = floor($height * ($thumb_width / $width)); // decrease height same percentage as width
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height); // imagecreatetruecolor() returns an image object representing a black image of the specified size.
        var_dump($upload_image);
        var_dump($thumb);

        // imagecreatefromjpeg function, which creates the image resource in memory out of the source image path which was initialized in the constructor
        if(preg_match('/[.](jpg|jpeg)$/i', $filename)) {
            $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/i', $filename)) {
            $image_source = imagecreatefromgif($upload_image);
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/i', $filename)) {
            $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($upload_image);
        } else {
            $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload_image);
        }
        var_dump($image_source);
        // Copy and resize part of the image with resampling based on the provided parameters and generates the thumbnail image in memory.
        imagecopyresampled($thumb,$image_source,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);

        // imagejpeg function which saves the in-memory thumbnail image to the desired path on the disk
        if(preg_match('/[.](jpg|jpeg)$/i', $filename)) {
            imagejpeg($thumb,$thumbnail_image,100);
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/i', $filename)) {
            imagegif($thumb,$thumbnail_image,100);
        } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/i', $filename)) {
            imagepng($thumb,$thumbnail_image,100);
        } else {
            imagejpeg($thumb,$thumbnail_image,100);
        }

    }
```

JS code:

```
(function($) {

    /* SIDE SCROLL WHOLE */

    var scrollArea = $('.left-arrow').next(),
        scrollEnd = scrollArea.width(),
        leftArrow = $('.left-arrow'),
        rightArrow = $('.right-arrow');

    leftArrow.hide();

    rightArrow.click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev().animate({scrollLeft: scrollEnd}, 1000); // scroll just area belong to the arrow
        leftArrow.show();
        rightArrow.hide();
    });

    leftArrow.click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 1000); // scroll just area belong to the arrow
        leftArrow.hide();
        rightArrow.show();
    });

    /* SIDE SCROLL PARTIAL*/
    /*
    var leftArrowPartial = $('.left-arrow-partial'),
        rightArrowPartial = $('.right-arrow-partial'),
        scrollAreaPartial = leftArrowPartial.next(),
        frameWidth = scrollAreaPartial.width(), // width of div showed on display
        scrollElmtWidth = scrollAreaPartial[0].scrollWidth, // width of div also with hidden part
        scrollAmount = 0,
        distance = 0,
        maxDistance = scrollElmtWidth - frameWidth, // width of whole also with hidden part - width which must be uncovered by scrolling
        scrollStep =  maxDistance/3; // divide all resolution to 4 steps

    leftArrowPartial.hide(); // if it is start of scrolling area, no need left arrow

    rightArrowPartial.click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();

        distance = scrollAreaPartial.scrollLeft();

        // if scrolled distance is less then max distance + 1/4 px each time -> after max distance have not to count + 1/4 px
        if (distance < maxDistance) {

            scrollAmount += scrollStep;

            // scroll just area belong to the arrow
            $(this).prev().animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 100);

            leftArrowPartial.show();

        }

        // hide right arrow on end of srolling area
        if (scrollAmount >= maxDistance) {
            rightArrowPartial.hide();
        }

    });


    leftArrowPartial.click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();

        distance = scrollAreaPartial.scrollLeft();

        //if (scrollAmount > maxDistance) {scrollAmount = maxDistance}

        // if it is start of scroll area -> cannot discount - 1/4 px
        if (scrollAmount > 0) {

            scrollAmount -= scrollStep;

            // scroll just area belong to the arrow
            $(this).next().animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 100);

            rightArrowPartial.show();

        }

        // hide right arrow on start of srolling are
        if (scrollAmount <= 0) {
            leftArrowPartial.hide();
        }

    });*/

    /* DRAG AND DROP IMG UPLOAD */

    // preventing page from redirecting
    $("html").on("dragover", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("html").on("drop", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); });

    // Drag enter
    $('.add-item__upload-area').on('dragenter', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Drag over
    $('.add-item__upload-area').on('dragover', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.add-item__dropzone').css({border: '2px dashed #111'});
    });

    $('.add-item__upload-area').on('dragleave', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.add-item__dropzone').css({border: '2px dashed #888'});

    });

    // Open file browser
    $('.add-item__add-photo-btn').click(function() {
        $('#input-files').trigger('click'); // execute input type file after click on button
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // create object to keep img files for modification
    var data = {};

    // Files added by drop to dropzone area
    $('.add-item__upload-area').on('drop', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        var totalFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length;

        // fill form by files from input
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {

            var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i], // Get list of the files dropped to area
                url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            // Control of size and format
            if (file) {

                var fileType = file.type, // get image format (jpg, gif, ...)
                    fileSize = file.size, // get file size
                    maxFileSize = 10485760, // set up max file size
                    typeReg = /^image\/(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/; // allow jpg, png, jpeg, gif

                if ( typeReg.test(fileType) && fileSize <= maxFileSize )  {

                    // fill object for file modifications by img files
                    data['file_'+i] = file;

                    // create temp url to img object for creating thumbnail and append img with temp src to thumbnail__wraper div
                    $('.thumbnail__wrapper').append('<div class="thumbnail" id="file_'+ i +'"><img class="imageThumb" src="' + url + '" title="' + file.name + '"/><br/><a class="remove">Zmazať</a></div>');

                    $('.add-item__add-photo-btn-area').find('p').hide();

                    //URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                } else {
                    if (!typeReg.test(fileType)) {
                        alert('This file type is unsupported.');
                    } else if (fileSize > maxFileSize) {
                        alert('This file reach max supported size.');
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    });

    // Files added by selecting in file browser
    $('#input-files').on('change', function(){

        var totalFiles = $('#input-files')[0].files.length; // get number of uploaded files from input element

        // modify ordering of fields inside data object according to order from sortable ui
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            // By appending [0] to the jQuery object will return the first DOM element. Get <input> element from object.
            var file = $('#input-files')[0].files[i], // Get first file from list of files selected with the <input type="file">
                url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            if (file) {

                var fileType = file.type, // get image format (jpg, gif, ...)
                    fileSize = file.size, // get file size
                    maxFileSize = 10485760, // set up max file size
                    typeReg = /^image\/(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/; // allow jpg, png, jpeg, gif

                if ( typeReg.test(fileType) && fileSize <= maxFileSize )  {

                    // fill object for file modifications by img files
                    data['file_'+i] = file;

                    // create temp url to img object for creating thumbnail and append img with temp src to thumbnail__wraper div
                    $('.thumbnail__wrapper').append('<div class="thumbnail" id="file_'+ i +'"><img class="imageThumb" src="' + url + '" title="' + file.name + '"/><br/><a class="remove">Zmazať</a></div>');

                    $('.add-item__add-photo-btn-area').find('p').hide();

                    //URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                } else {
                    if (!typeReg.test(fileType)) {
                        alert('This file type is unsupported.');
                    } else if (fileSize > maxFileSize) {
                        alert('This file reach max supported size.');
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        //console.log(data);
        //uploadData(formData); // send data via ajax to upload.php

    });

    // Remove field of data obj after click on remove button
    $('.add-item__dropzone').on('click','.remove', function() {
        // remove choosen field
        delete data[$(this).parent().attr('id')];
        $(this).parent('.thumbnail').remove();
        if ($(this).parent('.thumbnail').empty()) {
            $('.add-item__add-photo-btn-area').find('p').show();
        }
    });

    // Make images sortable
    $('.thumbnail__wrapper').sortable({
        axis: 'x', // axis in which sort is possible
        update: function (event, ui) {
            // get all ids (item-1, ....) from li elements (setted as sortable) of list in form item[]=1&item[]=2

            var reorderList = $(this).sortable('serialize');

            //console.log(reorderList);
            // fill FormData object by files from data array after order change
            var formData = new FormData();
            var dataLength = Object.keys(data).length;

            //console.log(data);
            data = changeOrder(data, reorderList);
            //console.log(data);

        }
    });

    // Change order of files inside object data
    function changeOrder(obj, order) {
        var newObject = {};
        // if the g flag is used, all results matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups will not.
        var matches = order.match(/=/g);
        var count = matches.length;
        // file[]=1&file[]=0&file[]=2 => ["file[]=1", "file[]=0", "file[]=2"]
        var arrayOfOrderValues = order.split('&');

        // console.log(arrayOfOrderValues);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            // get values in appropriate format ["file[]=1", "file[]=0", "file[]=2"] => file_1, file_0, file_2
            orderKey = 'file_' + arrayOfOrderValues[i].substring(arrayOfOrderValues[i].lastIndexOf("=") + 1);

            // console.log(orderKeyValue);
            // check if object contains key(property) as orderKeyValue and then do next step
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(orderKey)) {
                // fill value of obj['file_1'] to newObject['file_0'] - ex. in first loop
                newObject['file_'+i] = obj[orderKey];
            }

        }
        return newObject;
    };

    // Sending AJAX request and upload file
    function uploadData(formdata){

        $.ajax({
            url: '_inc/upload.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: formdata,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                //addThumbnail(response); // if success - create thumbnail
            }
        })
    };

    $('.test').on('submit', function() {
        event.preventDefault();

        //URL.revokeObjectURL();

        var formData = new FormData(); // Create form
        console.log(data);

        var count = Object.keys(data).length; // count fields of object

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            formData.append('files[]', data['file_'+i]); // append data to form -> (key, value), file[0] first file from list of files !!! key must have [] for array
        }
        console.log(count);

        uploadData(formData); // send data via ajax to upload.php

    });


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing an image before uploading it; I would do that on the client-side, and you can perfectly do that by using vanilla javascript only. Think about tons of users uploading the files to your server; that would mean tons of unnecessary server load. If you can do something on the client-side and that does not impact security, I'd do it on the client side.

To do it in js, proceed via the following steps:

- Assume you have uploaded one file to:

```
<input type="file" id="my-upload" />
```

- Grab the upload via:

```
const upload = document.getElementById('my-upload').files[0]
```

- Eventually check the files' `MIME type` and its size to respect your conditions, via `upload.type` and `upload.size`.
- Initiate a two-dimensional [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API), which will be needed as frame to resize your image:

```
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

- Use the `FileReader` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read your file into a `base64` string:

```
let reader = new FileReader();

// Read the contents of the file
reader.readAsDataURL(upload);
```

Once that conversion finished, the `load` event will be triggered on your FileReader object, holding the according `base64` string under the `result` property. This is where the real fun starts:

```
reader.onload = function () {

  // Initiate image element; needed to retrieve the originally uploaded file's
  // width and height, to maintain proportions while resizing
  let dummyImg = new Image(
    0,
    0
  );

  // Set the 'src' attribute of that element to your string
  dummyImg.src = this.result;

  // The line above causes your base64 string to be loaded into the 'img'
  // element. When that process finishes, the 'load' event is triggered on 
  // your image

  dummyImg.onload = function () {

    // Get the original width and height of the uploaded file
    const origWidth = dummyImg.naturalWidth;
    const origHeight = dummyImg.naturalHeight;

    // Calculate ratio factor to maintain aspect ratio after resizing
    // You may replace '300' with your desired width in pixels
    const desiredWidth = 300;

    const ratio = desiredWidth / origWidth;

    // Calculate the corresponding height, matching 'desiredWidth'
    const correspondingHeight = ratio * origHeight;

    // Set canvas' width and height according to what has been calculated
    canvas.width = desiredWidth;
    canvas.height = correspondingHeight;

    // Draw the image into the canvas
    canvasContext.drawImage(
      dummyImg,
      0,
      0,
      desiredWidth,
      correspondingHeight
    );

    // Convert resized image back to base64 string
    const resizedImage = canvas.toDataURL(
      upload.type,
      1.0 // quality. change this to a value < 1.0 for mime types that allow
          // lossy compression, such as jpeg, to allow for further compression
          // (with quality loss though). On file types that do not allow for
          // lossy compression, this value will have no effect.
    );

    // 'resizedImage' will be the base64 string representation of your 
    // uploaded file, resized based on a width of 300 pixels,
    // conserving the aspect ratio. You can now simply submit that to your 
    // server, as PHP works pretty well with base64 strings when it comes to
    // file contents.

    // Note that you do not need formData for this anymore, now that 
    // you're working with a simple (base64) string; you can easily 
    // submit the data as simple string to the server. So try to 
    // simply submit the value 'resizedImage' to your server HERE,
    // just like you would submit any other string, and grab it on
    // your server side like you would do it with any other string

    // If you bind this code as change listener to your upload element
    // , I would store the value of 'resizedImage' in a variable,
    // which you then submit to the server upon form submit. I 
    // leave that decision up to you.

  }

}
```

**CONCRETE IMPLEMENTATION**

```
// Initiate storage variable for resized image
var resizedFile;

function resizeImage() {

const upload = document.getElementById('your-upload').files[0];

let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

let reader = new FileReader();

reader.readAsDataURL(upload);

reader.onload = function () {

  let dummyImg = new Image(
    0,
    0
  );

  dummyImg.src = this.result;

  dummyImg.onload = function () {

    const origWidth = dummyImg.naturalWidth;
    const origHeight = dummyImg.naturalHeight;

    const desiredWidth = 300;

    const ratio = desiredWidth / origWidth;

    const correspondingHeight = ratio * origHeight;

    canvas.width = desiredWidth;
    canvas.height = correspondingHeight;

    canvasContext.drawImage(
      dummyImg,
      0,
      0,
      desiredWidth,
      correspondingHeight
    );

    const resizedImage = canvas.toDataURL(
      upload.type,
      1.0
    );

    // If you bind this code as change listener to your upload element
    // , I would store the value of 'resizedImage' in a variable,
    // which you then submit to the server upon form submit. I 
    // leave that decision up to you. Personally, I prefer storing 
    // the obtained base64 string in a variable, and then post to 
    // the server on submit.
    resizedFile = resizedImage;

  }

} 

}

// Attach as change listener to your <input type="file" id="your-upload"/> element, such that it reacts everytime you upload a file

document.getElementById('your-upload').addEventListener('change',resizeImage);
```

Comment: Thank you for good suggestion. Is it possible to implement it with my current JS code? I do not use FileReader. I just store files grabed from input element or by drop to object data and then process them.

Comment: You can implement this wherever you want. FileReader is native javascript, so if you want to use this approach, you may change the upload listener to my code above, and just submit `resizedImage` to your server, and that's it.

Comment: Thank you one more time, your code is very clear and I could not find better one. But my JS skills are not good. Can you please check where I made mistake.

Comment: There's no point in trying to integrate my code into yours, my code above works on its own, without anything else needed. My suggestion is that you forget entirely about your code, and simply add my code as a function as an event listener to the `change` event of your `<input type="file" />` element, because you need absolutely nothing else for this to be working, except from then using the base64 string on the PHP side. And you can easily find out how to do that with a little research ('how to store base64 string as file in PHP?')

Comment: I've detailed the implementation in my answer, but it's basically copy-paste. Anyway, it may help you further.

Comment: I am extremely grateful.
So I implemented it like you wrote it is working well. 
Just one problem that  I get error ```script.js:243 Uncaught ReferenceError: resizedFile is not defined``` when I want to use resizedFile outside of function. 
If I console.log resizedFile inside dummyImg.onload function it shows me desired string.

Comment: First, it would be cool if you could upvote and / or accept an answer that solved your problem; which is a nice way of showing how grateful you are, and which is basically the principle of this forum ;) Have you copy-pasted my code above? Initiated `var resizedFile;` at the very top? And in the `onload` event, did you correctly assign `resizedFile = resizedImage;` ? Then what you mention should definitely not happen

Comment: Hope it worked all out then. If you copy-pasted the code written below `CONCRETE IMPLEMENTATION`, and did not overwrite `resizedFile` anywhere, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

So finally (after little wake up - I realized that `onload` is asynchronous function) I implemented code from DevelJoe in this way. I do not know if it is correct way but I hope I did not screw it up.

*During each change event on input field type file*

- I check size and img type and then resize image and then create preview

```
    // Files added by selecting in file browser
    $('#input-files').on('change', function(){

        var totalFiles = $('#input-files')[0].files.length; // get number of uploaded files from input element

        // Fill form by files from input
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {

            // By appending [0] to the jQuery object will return the first DOM element. Get <input> element from object.
            var file = $('#input-files')[0].files[i]; // Get first file from list of files selected with the <input type="file">

            // If file is not empty control size and type and show temp image
            if (file) {
                if ( checkImageTypeAndSize(file) )  {
                    
                    resizeImageAndCreatePreview(file);

                }
            }

        }

    });
```

*Here is my modified code for image resizing:*

- I added function to convert base64 img to blob
- then I create `new File` and storage files in object `data` which I can modify due to sortable function
- after submit I upload all files to server via upload.php

```
    /* IMAGE RESIZE */ 


    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
        var byteString;
        if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
            byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        else
            byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

        // separate out the mime component
        var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

        // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
        var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
    }
    

    function resizeImageAndCreatePreview(file) {

        const upload = file;
        var resizedFile;
        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        let canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
        let reader = new FileReader();
       
        reader.readAsDataURL(upload);

        reader.onload = function () {

            let dummyImg = new Image(
                0,
                0
            ); 

            dummyImg.src = this.result;

            dummyImg.onload = function () {

                const origWidth = dummyImg.naturalWidth;
                
                const origHeight = dummyImg.naturalHeight;

                const desiredWidth = 1024;

                const ratio = desiredWidth / origWidth;
                
                const correspondingHeight = ratio * origHeight;
                
                canvas.width = desiredWidth;
                canvas.height = correspondingHeight;

                canvasContext.drawImage(
                    dummyImg,
                    0,
                    0,
                    desiredWidth,
                    correspondingHeight
                );

                const resizedImage = canvas.toDataURL(
                    upload.type,
                    1.0
                );

                var resizedFileURL = resizedImage;

                var blob = dataURItoBlob(resizedFileURL);

                resizedFile = new File( [blob], upload.name, { type: upload.type, size: upload.size } );  

                var url = URL.createObjectURL(resizedFile);

                mark = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 7);

                // fill object for file modifications by img files
                data['file_'+mark] = resizedFile;

                // create temp url to img object for creating thumbnail and append img with temp src to thumbnail__wraper div
                $('.thumbnail__wrapper').append('<div class="thumbnail" id="file_'+ mark +'"><img class="imageThumb" src="' + url + '" title="' + file.name + '"/><br/><a class="remove">Zmazať</a></div>');

                $('.add-item__add-photo-btn-area').find('p').hide();

                console.log(data);
            }       
        }

    };
```

Please correct me if I do something wrong. This is first time I do something similar to this.